# Sum $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2^x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Calculate $\sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x}{2^x}$

So, this series converges by ratio test. How do I find the sum? Any hints?

Comment: Let the sum be $S$. Then $2S-S=\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x+1-x}{2^x}$.

Comment: I din't get how 2S-S = x+1-x !

Comment: We have $S=\frac{0}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\cdots$. So $2S=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\cdots$. Subtract, "lining up" powers of $2$. We get $2S-S=\frac{1-0}{1}+\frac{2-1}{2}+\frac{3-2}{4}+\frac{4-3}{8}+\cdots$. This sum is $2$ (geometric progression) so $S=2$.

Comment: Shouldn't 2S be 0/1+2/2+4/4+6/8+8/16+...

Comment: My version leaves out the first term (obviously harmless) and cancels a $2$ from top and bottom for all other terms.

Comment: ohh .. now I see what you meant .. Thanks a lot for your patience ..

Comment: You are welcome. Anyway, I like it when an argument of mine is challenged. Same idea works for $\sum nr^n$ where $|r|\lt 1$.

Comment: This must have been asked a thousand times before on this site...

Comment: Quite so: alas, mathematical expressions aren't "searchable", so locating duplications mostly relies on potential respondents' memories of where they saw or replied to an earlier appearance of the question. (I know _I've_ said something about this sum before -- some time ago...)

Comment: [Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{2^k} = 2$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2),
[Why does $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ converge to 2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441481/why-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n-converge-to-2),
[What does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{2^k}$ converge to?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1325254).
If you [search in approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%20k%20%7B2%5Ek%7D%24&p=1) you can find more questions about the same sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a first step, let us prove that

$$f(r) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}$$

if $r \in (-1,1)$. This is the geometric series. If you haven't seen this proven before, here's a proof. Define

$$S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N r^n.$$

Then

$$r S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N r^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} r^n = S_N - 1 + r^{N+1}.$$

Solve this equation for $S_N$, obtaining

$$S_N = \frac{1-r^{N+1}}{1-r}$$

and send $N \to \infty$ to conclude.

The sum above converges absolutely, so we can differentiate term by term. Doing so we get

$$f'(r) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n r^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}.$$

(Precisely speaking, the sum in the middle is ill-defined at $r=0$, in that it has the form $0/0$. However, $f'(0)=1$ still holds. This doesn't matter for this problem, but it should be noted regardless.) Now multiply by $r$ to change it into your form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n r^n = \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}.$$

Now substitute $r=1/2$.

Comment: why does r = $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Wow .. Thanks for such an awesome answer

Comment: @mathtastic With $r=1/2$ the summand is $n (1/2)^n = n/2^n$, as desired.

Answer (score 3):

If you write out the first few (non-zero) terms, $ \ \frac{1}{2^1} \ + \ \frac{2}{2^2} \ + \ \frac{3}{2^3} \ + \ \ldots \ $ , another approach suggests itself, which is to use a "stacking" of infinite series (this would be along the lines of Jacob Bernoulli-style [1680s] ) :

$$  \frac{1}{2^1} \ + \ \frac{2}{2^2} \ + \ \frac{3}{2^3} \ + \ \ldots \ \ = $$

$$ \frac{1}{2^1} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^2} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^3} \ + \ \ldots $$
$$  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \ \ \ + \ \frac{1}{2^2} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^3} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^4} \ + \ \ldots $$
$$  \quad \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \ \  + \ \frac{1}{2^3} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^4} \ + \ \frac{1}{2^5} \ + \ \ldots \ \ = $$

$$ 1 \ + \ \frac{1}{2} \ + \ \frac{1}{4} \ + \ \frac{1}{8} \ + \ \ldots \ = \ \ 2 \ \ .  $$

[summing the sub-series in each row individually]

More modern methods (such as described by **Ian**) are more elegant, but Bernoulli got a lot of "mileage" out of this approach and extensions of it back then.

Comment: In modern notation this looks like: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{2^n} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$. The clever trick is the interchange of order, which is again an application of the absolute convergence. From a problem-solving perspective, the hard part is indexing the "triangular array" correctly!