# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{2^k}$

Tags: summation

Evaluate $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{2^k}$$

Comment: I've posted answers to essentially this same question several times.  This question seems to get asked more frequently than all others.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm Polish. How to find?

Comment: This is his first, he does not know that it is a duplicate. Anyway he is not asking anything, just posting a problem.

Comment: This is "$\infty$", is to be "$n$"

Comment: Although the question to which it was an answer isn’t actually a duplicate, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30741/12042) completely answers the present question using only very elementary techniques. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/441506/12042) was for the infinite series, but the same technique works here.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $$S = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}(\frac{k}{2^k})$$

Try evaluating $S - \frac{S}{2}$ and you will see the trend.

Answer (score 1):

You have that:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n r^k=\displaystyle\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

derive the both side to get an expression to this sum, observe that your first term is $1$ not zero. Take $r=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{2^k} =  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{2^{k-1}} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k - 1}{2^{k-1}} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\right) =  ....$$

Good?

Comment: Good or wrong? I'm not sure.