# Compute the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{10}{\frac{k}{2^k}}$

Tags: summation, contest-math

Compute the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}{\dfrac{k}{2^k}}$$

This question is taken from SMO junior (I can't remember which year it is). I have no idea how to start. Can anyone give some hint?

By writing out the sum, one has

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + ... + \frac{10}{1024}$$

but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: The sum is finite. Just start writing out the terms, find the common denominator among the terms (which is $2^{10}$), and add 'em up.

Comment: @idonknow how do you normally add fractions?

Comment: if you will have more terms, you can rewrite it as the sum of geometric series.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate... although the posts I can find are for the infinite sum (see e.g. [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337937/why-sum-k-1-infty-frack2k-2?lq=1), the techniques (differentiation, for instance) are the same, and the topic has been treated numerous times at length. [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155422/evaluate-sum-limits-k-1n-frack2k?lq=1) is even a direct match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{k}{2^k}&=\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=1}^k(1)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{k=j}^N\frac{1}{2^k}\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^N\left(\frac{(1/2)^j-(1/2)^{N+1}}{1-1/2}\right)\\\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^N(1/2)^j-(1/2)^N\,N\\\\
&=2-(1/2)^{N-1}-(1/2)^N\,N
\end{align}$$

For $N=10$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10} \frac{k}{2^k}=2-(1/2)^9-10(1/2)^{10}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}{\dfrac{k}{2^k}}=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{4} + \frac{3}{8} + ... + \frac{10}{1024}=\frac{2^9+2*2^8+3*2^7+...+10*2^0}{2^{10}}$$
and notice that the numerator can be written as:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8+2^9+ \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8+ \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+ \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+  \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+  \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+  \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+ \\
2^0+2^1+2^2+  \\
2^0+2^1  \\
2^0= \\
=2^{10}-1+2^9-1+2^8-1+2^7-1+2^6-1+2^5-1+2^4-1+2^3-1+2^2-1+2-1=  \\
=2+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8+2^9+2^{10}-10= \\
=2\frac{2^{10}-1}{2-1}-10=2^{11}-12=2048-12=2036
\end{array}
$$
Thus:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}{\dfrac{k}{2^k}}=\frac{2036}{1024}=\frac{509}{256}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
S=\sum_{k=1}^{10}{k\over2^k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{10}{k\over2^{k+1}}=2\sum_{k=2}^{11}{k-1\over 2^k}=2\sum_{k=1}^{10}{k-1\over 2^k}+{10\over2^{10}}=2S-\sum_{k=1}^{10}{1\over2^{k-1}}+{10\over2^{10}}\\
\implies  S=2-{2\over2^{10}}-{10\over2^{10}}=2-{3\over2^8}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{10}\frac{k}{2^k} = \sum_{j = 1}^{10}\sum_{k=j}^{10}\frac{1}{2^k}$$
Apply power series formulae to ${\frac{1}{2^k}}$